# Expo OTA Updates not working on first launch

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am working with [Expo's OTA Updates](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/updates/) and for some reason my app doesn't apply the update until the second time opening the app.

For example, I make some changes and run `expo publish`, I go ahead and open the app and there are no changes. I then close the app, and reopen and the changes are realized.

I'm looking to both download and apply changes right from the initial opening of the app.

`app.json`

```
"updates": {
   "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing `fallbackToCacheTimeout` to any n > 0.

This allows the app to download and apply any updates within n time before reverting back to previous cached version of the app.